# Problem Setting up Handlers for Logger in a Module

Tags: python, logging

I would like to setup a logger to a file in a module that is used in multiple executables. I have attempted this based on many threads found here, but I am still having trouble.  The logger is writing to both sys.stderr and the file specified in the filehandler, but I expect it to write only to the specified file.  Here is my code which is just after imports in the module:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
stream_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

file_handler = logging.FileHandler('debug_out.log', 'w')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

print('root', logging.getLogger().handlers, logging.getLevelName(logging.getLogger().getEffectiveLevel()))
print(logger, logger.handlers, logging.getLevelName(logger.getEffectiveLevel()))
```

The output of the last 2 lines is:

```
root [<StreamHandler <stderr> (NOTSET)>] WARNING
<Logger GPUmodules.GPUmodule (DEBUG)> [<StreamHandler <stderr> (WARNING)>, <FileHandler /home/rick/pydev/debug_out.log (DEBUG)>] DEBUG
```

With this code, all logger.debug messages are written to both stderr and the file,but the expectation is that only the specified log file will get debug logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By modifying the formatter above, I found that is was not the stream_handler I defined that was writing log messages to the terminal. Since it was the root logger that was writing them, I set propagate to False, right after creating the logger in the above code:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.propagate = False
```